# Variable is not changing value according to my list

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm writing a script in PowerShell to automate creation of AD users. One of the conditions I use is to check if the user already exists, then to `Write-Host "User exists"` and move to the next element in the array. However, when I run the script, it gives me an odd behavior. I'll put the code then explain what happens when I put in breakpoints.

```
$MACList = Get-Content $Path\MACs.txt
foreach ($MAC in $MACList){
   $MABName = Get-ADUser $MAC
   if ($MABName -ne $null) {
      Write-Host "MAB already exists, moving to next"
   } else {
      # create the new user
   }
```

When I run the script with breakpoints I can see that `$MACList` contains the MACs in the file. When I move to the next step, I can see that `$MAC` contains each element as I traverse the `$MACList` array. When it gets to the `$MABName` line, `$MAC` indeed contains a MAC address, so it should go find if I have that user and set `$MABName` to that user. It seems to keep the same value if the Get-User cmdlet doesn't return an object. Any ideas on why this might happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-ADUser` throws an error for non-existing users, so the variable retains its previous value. Use the `-Filter` parameter to avoid this issue:

```
$MABName = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$MAC'"
```